# Compare one month of two year with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there a way to compare one month of two year with Highcharts Columns ?

See the  exemple below :

[image]

Data structure looks like:

```
myData[0] = { data1:"0.00", data2:"0.00", data3:"868.00", month:"june", numMonth:"11", data4:"mydata4", year:"2014" } 
myData[1] = { data1:"0.00", data2:"0.00", data3:"737.00", month:"june", numMonth:"11", data4:"mydata4", year:"2015" }
```

By comparing theses datas, I would like to put years below my columns.

Thanks !

Comment: Well yes, but it depends on your data and it's structure.

Comment: The data are objects like this : 

myData[0] = {
 data1:"0.00",
 data2:"0.00",
 data3:"2211.00",
 month:"novembre",
 numMonth:"11",
 data4:"mydata4",
 year:"2015"
}

And for the same month, I can have two different years :

myData[1] = {
 data1:"0.00",
 data2:"0.00",
 data3:"2211.00",
 month:"novembre",
 numMonth:"11",
 data4:"mydata4",
 year:"2016"
}

thanks for your reply ;)

Comment: Yes. For a more specific answer, you'll need to add a more specific question.

Comment: What are you asking because 'comparing months' doesn't mean anything. Also, your data structure doesn't match what's shown in the graph.

Comment: Sorry, that's not clear. I edit my post just right know.

myData[0] = { data1:"0.00", data2:"0.00", data3:"868.00", month:"june", numMonth:"11", data4:"mydata4", year:"2014" } 
    myData[1] = { data1:"0.00", data2:"0.00", data3:"737.00", month:"june", numMonth:"11", data4:"mydata4", year:"2015" }


By comparing theses datas, I would like to put years below my columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your data easily to format expected by highcharts.

```
myData = []
myData[0] = {
  data1: "0.00",
  data2: "0.00",
  data3: "2211.00",
  month: "november",
  numMonth: "11",
  data4: "mydata4",
  year: "2015"
}
myData[1] = {
  data1: "0.00",
  data2: "0.00",
  data3: "2211.00",
  month: "november",
  numMonth: "11",
  data4: "mydata4",
  year: "2016"
}

const series = myData.map((o) => {
  return {
    type: 'column',
    name: o.year,
    data: [{x: Number(o.numMonth), y: Number(o.data3)}]
  }
})

console.log(series)

const options = {
  xAxis: { categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] },
  series: series
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xw3w1zve/

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that's not what I'm searching for. It has to look like to the picture I've attached to my post.

Comment: It looks like above to me. You just need to change colors, add dataLabels etc.